# `#include <gmpxx.h>` fails to compile with `fatal error: iosfwd: No such file or directory`

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gmp

I am trying to use the GMP library in my C program as follows:

```c
/* gmp test */
#include <gmpxx.h>

main() {
  printf("yay, it works!\n");
}
```

and I am compiling this on Linux with `gcc -o a.out my-c-program.c`, but I get this error when compiling the `#include <gmpxx.h>` line above:

```
gcc -o a.out my-c-program.c
In file included from my-c-program.c:2:0:
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:34:18: fatal error: iosfwd: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu May  5 11:34:16
```

I looked at the `gmpxx.h` file under `/usr/include/gmpxx.h`, and on line 34, there is the line `#include <iosfwd>`, which explains the error. But how do I fix it? Am I missing a library? Or am I missing something in my `gcc` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct header name for GMP as C library is `gmp.h`.

The `gmpxx.h` is suited for GMP's [C++ Class Interface](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Class-Interface), which is built on top of `gmp.h` and requires to compile with C++ compiler such as `g++`.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error in gmp.h
`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h:34:10: fatal error: 'iosfwd' file not found`
This is while I'm inside docker using 'gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) '

When I compile the same code on my local machine it compiles without any error using `gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)`
Any idea what I might be missing?